# error 404 - I can no longer access my Wordpress administration page

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, admin

following an error on my part I can no longer access my WP administration page: I changed the main URL name by naming it like that of my home page in the "settings" tab from WP. And boom.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfNZR.png)

My host (Hostinger) found what he calls a "code problem" but cannot fix it. I did their FTP procedure but nothing works. It's been several weeks of work on this site, I'm a little disgusted.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

(sorry for the translation i'm french)

I reset the site to FTP with the latest version of WP without success.
I clear DNS cache and browser cache, without success.

I hope recover my admin page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your Wordpress installation's database, perhaps through phpMyAdmin, look inside `wp_options` table for the row with the value 'siteurl' under the `option_name` column. Inside this row, you will find your main url under the `option_value` column. You should be able to access your admin area via this url by appending the subpath '/wp-admin' to it (if the value is http://example.com, the path will be http://example.com/wp-admin).

If, despite following these steps, you still cannot access your admin area, ONLY AFTER MAKING A BACKUP, update this row with the original main url in place of the url currently saved.

Good luck.